# Как сделать так чтобы сообщение которое ты написал например /ask Отправлялось в нужную группу по чат-id

Tags: python, telebot

Я делаю бота мафию и добавляю функции например Писать от имени Админа и вопрос как сделать чтобы например /ask Тест отправлялся в нужную группу?

Comment: Предоставьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['ask'])
def ask(message):
   msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'что отправить?')
   bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, ask_2)


def ask_2(message):
    bot.send_message(-1...5, message.text)  # id группы или канала именно с дефисом
```

чтобы отправлять ботом сообщения в группу/канал бот должен быть участником канала и иметь разрешение на публикацию сообщений.

так же вам нужно знать id группы/канала, получить его можно:

```
import logging
logger = telebot.logger
telebot.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

- у `BotFather` в `/setjoingroups` выбрать `Enable`
- добавьте бота в группу/канал
- назначьте его администратором
- отправьте в канал сообщение, например `/start`

в консоли вы должны увидеть примерно следующее:

> 2020-05-04 20:57:03,847 (apihelper.py:55 PollingThread) DEBUG - TeleBot: "The server returned: 'b'{"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":661653078,\n"channel_post":{"message_id":4276,"chat":{"id":-100...413,"title":"%name channel%","type":"channel"},"date":1588615023,"text":"/start","entities":[{"offset":0,"length":6,"type":"bot_command"}]}}]}''"

где `id: -100...413` и есть id группы/канала